# Loading Android OpenGL ES 2.0 textures using an array, not a Buffer

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This question is similar to [How to get around the performance issues with Buffer.put() and Android OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437259/how-to-get-around-the-performance-issues-with-buffer-put-and-android-opengl) but I'm asking it because:

- It's slightly different - my issue is with textures, not vertex buffers
- Though the question is clear, it seems like most of the answers miss the point
- The question is 3 years old and maybe there's something new to solve my problem
- It really surprises me that this is an issue...I feel I must be misunderstanding something.

Anyway I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android.  I have a large texture (say 1024x1024) that must updated with every frame.  There is no way around this AFAIK - the content of the texture is essentially a video.

The problem is that the Android Java interface to OpenGL usings java.nio.Buffer objects, not arrays.  Specifically the last parameter of

```
public static void GLES20.glTexImage2D (int target, int level, int internalformat, int width, int height, int border, int format, int type, Buffer pixels)
```

is a Buffer, not a `byte[]` or `int[]`.

So, instead of generating the texture's content (for every frame) directly into an int[] that can then be passed to `glTexImage2D`, I have to generate the content into an int[], then call IntBuffer.put() for the entire huge array.  Traceview and calls to System.nanoTime() around the call show that this is a takes a lot of CPU, not surprisingly.

How does one work around this?  I tried to use IntBuffer.array() to get to the content as an array, but

- The `array()` call does not succeed for Buffers allocated with `IntBuffer.allocateDirect()`
- The `glTexImage2D()` call does not work for Buffers allocated with `IntBuffer.allocate()`

Other things I can think of:

- Call `glTexImage2D` from native code, I assume this isn't an issue with the Android GL native code interface
- Do the work on another thread.  But I don't know if this causes contention issues between the thread producing the texture content and the GL thread that calls glTexImage2D.  And anyway, it's still extra CPU cycles to copy memory when it isn't logically necessary.

I seems like this wouldn't be an issue if there was just a version of GLES20.glTexImage2D that took an int[] or other array type, instead of a Buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Buffer` in Android can be backed by an array. This means that the buffer is really just wrapping the array and modifications to the array are reflected in the buffer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/Buffer.html#array()

You can follow the code found on this website to create a `ByteBuffer` around a byte array:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/bytebuffer/convert-between-bytebuffer-and-byte-array/

Comment: I marked this as the Answer based on the link you provided (thanks!)The problem with the Buffer.array() method you mention is that glTexImage2D() doesn't like ByteBuffers created with allocate() - only allocateDirect().  And ByteBuffer.array() does not work for buffers created with allocate().  However, from the link you provided, I found that _first_ creating an array and _then_ creating the ByteBuffer with ByteBuffer.wrap() seems to work.  This is surprising since the ByteBuffer returned from wrap() is not a "direct" buffer...so I'm worried things will blow up later.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that glTexImage2D() is too slow to load frames from real-time video.
For this you should use the EGL Image extensions and EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID as described in this article:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-opengl-es-to-accelerate-apps-with-legacy-2d-guis

Also, look at the TextureView class.